# Guardar imagen en MongoDB usando react + expressJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

Estoy intentando guardar una imagen en MongoDB cargandola desde mi pagina web usando React "drag and drop" con `react-drop-zone`, tengo un servidor expressJS, que disponibiliza un metodo (POST) para guardar la imagen en MongoDB mi objeto File (es mi imagen cargada desde mi pagina web) que logro recibir de mi formulario esta compuesto por lo siguiente:

```
{
   "category":"1",
   "codbar":"1",
   "name":"1",
   "photo":{
      "File":{
         "lastModified":"1593991559622",
         "lastModifiedDate":"Sun Jul 05 2020 18:25:59 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)",
         "name":"my_image.jpg",
         "path":"/Users/myuser/Downloads/my_image.jpg",
         "size":"24638",
         "type":"image/jpeg",
         "webkitRelativePath":""
      }
   }
}
```

Mi ruta POST para guardar la imagen:

```
router.post("/product/create/", create);
```

Invoco el servicio desde mi pagina front de esta forma:

```
export const createProduct = (product) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/product/create/`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: product,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

No he podido hacer que el formulario llegue al servidor correctamente debido a que el body siempre esta llegando vacío.

Si lograra solucionar ello tampoco se como armar el Modelo del schema Mongo, lo he construído asi pero no se que poner en el atributo `data`:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

    photo: {
                data: Buffer,
                contentType: String
            },
    }
);
```

Comment: Mi pregunta es: ¿pretendes guardar la imagen como dato tipo `buffer` en la Base de Datos? Creo que tal vez sea mejor si la guardas en el sistema de archivos y en la BD sólo guardas la ruta a tu imagen. Por otro lado, para poder recibir datos que vienen en el cuerpo de la solicitud, debes usar un analizador (*parser*). En el mundo de NodeJS, para analizar datos binarios (archivos enviados por formulario) es muy popular el uso de [*multer*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por tu respuesta, asi es, yo quisiera guardar las imagenes como `buffer` no se si sea la mejor estrategia, ya que no quisiera que mi ejecutable fuera demasiado pesado pues son cientos de imagenes las que debo administrarar. Voy  a explorar multer, gracias.

Comment: Recuerda que un documento [BSON](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) tiene un [límite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) establecido en MongoDB. Guardar las imágenes como `buffer` en la base de datos no suele ser casi nunca la mejor estrategia. Saludos

Comment: no sabía eso @MauricioContreras gracias por tu aclaración, voy hacer una POC con lo que me propones. Muy amable

Answer (score -1):

puede usar firebase para cargar la imagen y generar un url que puede guardar en mongo db  para tener un optimo uso de ellas

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/403957)

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/403958)